# How to have a slider handle changes it's position in real time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm very new to game development and the Unity engine. I'm working on building an ocean simulation and wanted to implement a slider for depth that indicates how far the player is below the sea level. I wrote a script for the same but the handle of the slider doesn't change it's position automatically. I added a log line to check if the slider value was changing and it did so perfectly.

I've attached the code for reference.

Where am I going wrong ? What's the best solution ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Gauge : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider slider;
    float sliderValue;

    private void Start()
    {
        sliderValue = slider.value;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 depth = transform.position;

        if(depth.y< 11.867)
        {
            sliderValue = Mathf.Abs(depth.y);
            Debug.Log(sliderValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting `slider.value` in your `Update` loop, if you add `slider.value = sliderValue`, does it work?